# Friendship model, how to determine if a friendship model already exists between 2 users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, activemodel

I have a **Friend model**:

```
user_id, friend_id, status (approved, pending, ignored)
```

Given a user currently logged in, I want to be able to do something like

```
current_user.friendship_exists(@user)
```

Something to tell if a friendship exists for a logged in user looking at another user. To prevent either user from seeing "add friend" again when the record already exists.

Ideally I could show the user who created the friendship "Friend Request Sent"

And the user who needs to take action "respond to friendship request" where I can then so a approve & reject option.

Ideas on how I can do this? Show a button for either

- "Add Friend"
- "Friend Request Sent"
- "Respond to Friend Request"

Answer (score 2):

If you're just looking for the friendship_exists method, this is already built into Rails (assuming your User model has many friends):

```
current_user.friends.exists?(@user)
```

Comment: But which column is this checking, user_id or friend_id it's possible it could be in either. ANy thoughts on how to generate the 3 buttons?

Comment: It shouldn't matter which column it's checking since the exists? method will just check the friend objects and see if they match `@user`. As far as the buttons go, what sort of advice are you looking for? Your question was a little vague in that area.